# Can my external application access Redis Cache on azure

Tags: azure, redis, azure-redis-cache

Simple question. Can I use Azure Redis Cache for my external web application NOT hosted at Azure?

Comment: This is something that is trivial for try to do since creating a Redis Service cache gives you a connection string and associated key.

Comment: so we have a hosted application at a ISP in the US and we want to use Redis Cache on Azure. From Azure site they say:
Azure Redis Cache is based on the popular open-source Redis cache. It gives you access to a secure, dedicated Redis cache, managed by Microsoft and accessible from any application within Azure."

Does that statement mean we can only access Redis Cache on Azure can only be accessed by web application s hosted on Azure ?

Comment: thanks @DavidMakogon - Just to make sure I fully understand the solution , we can only access Redis Cache on azure on Azure?

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comment, this is a trivial thing to test, just by writing a simple local (console) app to connect and store/retrieve some keys. Something like:

```
var redisServer = '<yourcachename>.redis.cache.windows.net';
var redisKey = '<yourcachekey>=';
var client = redis.createClient(6380,redisServer, {auth_pass: redisKey, tls: {servername: redisServer}});

client.on("connect", function () {
   client.del("foo", redis.print);
   client.set("foo","bar", redis.print);
   client.get("foo",redis.print);
});
```

Which should return something like:

```
Reply: 1
Reply: OK
Reply: bar
```

There's nothing stopping this from running outside of Azure, which is exactly what I did, as a locally-run console app. I'm not sure why you had the impression you could only use the cache from an Azure-hosted service.

Note: You'll pay the price in latency and outbound bandwidth, but that's the case with *any* service you access from outside of the same Azure region as your Azure service.

Answer (score 1):

Simple Answer: Yes, you can. But as @David Makogon suggested you won't get desired performance in terms of latency etc.